# VBScript - Try to start a service until find a running instance of it

Tags: windows, service, vbscript

I have written the code below based on examples found here and in the Internet:

```
'Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objWMIService2, processItems, ProcessName, ServiceName, colListOfServices
ProcessName = "Agent.exe"
ServiceName = "EaseUS Agent"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set processItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where Name='"  & ProcessName & "'")
Set objWMIService2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService2.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & ServiceName & "'")
'Wscript.Echo ProcessName & ": " & processItems.Count

Do
'Start Service
For Each objService in colListOfServices
     objService.StartService()
Next
Loop While processItems.Count = 0
```

But its not working. Can you help me finding what is wrong there? If I enable the `Option Explicit` command the script says :

> objService is not defined.

If I comment the `Option Explicit` command it comes with a **Provider failure, code 80041004,origin SWbemObjectEx** related to the line `objService.StartService()`

Comment: objService variable not defined. Just add Dim objService between your "Do" and your "For Each" condition

Comment: Thank you Michalis! Yes, your suggestion worked. Now the script runs, but it seems it CAN NOT run the service as I expected. Maybe it is related to the name of the service EaseUS Agent it has a space between words. Could it be the problem? Maybe the objService.StartService() line has problem with the space character.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly question, but does the user have the permissions required to start this service?

Try running the .vbs as Administrator.

There is nothing wrong with the code itself and StartService does not have issues with spaces in service names.

I tested this myself with the following modification:

```
While processItems.Count = 0
'Start Service
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    Wscript.Echo objService.Name
    objService.StartService
Next
WScript.Sleep 5000
Wend
```

objService.Name will allow you to see the name of the service you're trying to start. This should have a value.

I also added a 5 second sleep between attempts to give the service some time to start.